# It is possible to handle a POST request using Scrapy from an HTML textfield?

Tags: javascript, python, post, scrapy, httprequest

It is the first time that I have to create a big project and now I'm stuck. My target is to create a website where a user have to search a recipe, this means that he inserts a string into the textfield and clicking on the button I have to show in the same HTML a list of recipes (taken from 3 websites that I can choose) based on the similarity between the text in the websites and the string the user inserted, using Scrapy and Solr. I created a simply *main.html* file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src="../index.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <html>

     <body>
      <h1> Recipes founder</h1>
      <form class="example" method="post" action="query">
        <input id ="query" type="text" placeholder="Insert a recipe.." name="search" 
         value="">
        <button id="searchRecipe" type="submit"><i></i>Search</button>
      </form>
     </body>

    </html>
```

The server is up and the get request to show the HTML file is in the index.js file:

```
    //require framework and middleware dependencies
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const logger = require('morgan');
    const methodOverride = require('method-override');
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

    const fs = require('fs-extra');



    //init framework
    const app = express();

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(fileUpload({
        limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }, safeFileNames: true,                                                 
        preserveExtension: 4, debug: false
    }));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.json({limit: '4MB'}));    // parse application/json
    app.use(methodOverride('_method'));



    // Request


    //Visualize HTML and CSS 
    app.get("/", function (request, response){
      //show this file when the "/" is requested
      response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'main.html'));
    });
    
    // Not correct -> must use Scrapy
    //app.post("/query", function(request, response) {
      //manda a scrapy? Scrapy prende js con selenium
    //})


    //default fallback handlers
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        const err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
      });

      // error handlers

      // development error handler
      // will print stacktrace
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });


    //start server
    app.set('port', 8000);

    const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });
```

This part works. Now my problem is that I'm a little bit confused about how to deal with the POST request of the user. I have to handle it using Scrapy and not JavaScript, because Scrapy must take the user string, the text from the webpages I give it and check the similarity between them, but I don't know if I'm wrong on setting my project in this way, or it is really possible that Scrapy can manage the request in this way. I read that Selenium is used to permit the communication between JS and Scrapy but I don't know if it is useful for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make Post-Requests with Scrapy, usually this is done using [FormRequests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) and should be enough for your use-case.

And yes, it is also possible to use Selenium with Scrapy for Handling JavaScript pages. There are alternatives to Selenium, like [Pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) and [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright).

However, if you can avoid it, you should go with plain Scrapy because it's faster and might save you a lot of headache in the long run because there are less sources for possible errors.

Comment: Then I use Scrapy to receive the POST request from the user?